# How to use the testrpc `evm_increaseTime` parameter from truffle console?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am creating smart contracts with truffle and testrpc. When writing unit tests I wish to change the block time to simulate different times that smart contracts may be called. How does one set `evm_increaseTime` inside truffle console?

Comment: Setting `evm_increaseTime` of ethereumjs-testrpc is implemented as an RPC call.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution is to override the `now` keyword in solidity, setting it to a value and then using that value later in the application (for testing purposes).

Comment: Interested to know how you did that. Small code snippet please?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the OP's answer with an example (Taken from [Status](https://github.com/status-im/status-network-token))

I suggest creating a `getTime()` function to return `now` in normal cases and a settable time when testing.

[SNTPlaceHolder.sol](https://github.com/status-im/status-network-token/blob/master/contracts/SNTPlaceHolder.sol)

```
/// @notice This function is overriden by the test Mocks.
function getTime() internal returns (uint256) {
    return now;
}
```

[SNTPlaceHolderMock.sol](https://github.com/status-im/status-network-token/blob/master/contracts/test/SNTPlaceHolderMock.sol)

```
uint256 mock_time;

function SNTPlaceHolderMock(...)
        SNTPlaceHolder(...) {
    mock_time = now;
}

function getTime() internal returns (uint256) {
    return mock_time;
}

function setMockedTime(uint256 _t) public {
    mock_time = _t;
}
```

We can now set the mocked time using `await sntPlaceHolderMock.setMockedTime(t);`

Answer (score 0):

1. 1.`evm_increaseTime`: increases the time for the next block.
2. 2.`evm_mine`: mines a new block.

You don't even need a Tardis or a DeLorean for this kind of time travel.

Let me explain how these functions work:

Every time a new block gets mined, the miner adds a timestamp to it. Let's say the transactions that created our zombies got mined in block 5.

Next, we call `evm_increaseTime` but, since the blockchain is immutable, there is no way of modifying an existing block. So, when the contract checks the time, it will not be increased.

If we run `evm_mine`, block number 6 gets mined (and timestamped) which means that, when we put the zombies to fight, the smart contract will "see" that a day has passed.

Putting it together, we can fix our test by traveling through time as follows:

```
await web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
  jsonrpc: "2.0",
  method: "evm_increaseTime",
  params: [86400],  // there are 86400 seconds in a day
  id: new Date().getTime()
}, () => { });

web3.currentProvider.send({
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    method: 'evm_mine',
    params: [],
    id: new Date().getTime()
});
```